# Split commas in string to <br /> in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a string (an address) containing commas that I wish to delimit to line-breaks inside some JSX. Doing the following merely outputs the `<br />` as a string:

`{address.split(',').join('<br />')}`

How can I do what I need to do, preferably retaining the commas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try wrap each address in `p` tag and don't use `<br />`,

```
var Component = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var addresses = this.props.addresses.split(',').map(function (address, index) {
            return <p key={index}>{ address }</p>; 
        });

        return <div className="addresses">{addresses}</div>;
    }
});
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/69z2wepo/20102/)

Answer (score 9):

To delimit based on commas, turning commas into line-breaks, while "preferably retaining the commas" (not sure you meant you want to retain them in the output, but interpreting that as such) you can try the following (works for me):

```
let newAddress = address.split(',').map(line => <span>{line},<br/></span>);
// span tag here only in order for JSX to accept br tag
```

Comment: nice! I was able to use this inline without a `let`. probably not the most idiomatic jsx i've ever written but it's what i (like the OP) was after 

Answer (score 5):

You can simply insert `<br/>` between the lines using [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```
{address.split(',').reduce((all, cur) => [
    ...all,
    <br/>,
    cur
])}
```

Comment: This is closest to using `join()` because it doesn't add a `<br/>` to the end of the list

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you want to use line breaks and not paragraphs. In that case, you can do:

```
function convertNewLines(_text) {
    let lines = _text.split('\n');
    let elements = [];
    for (let i=0; i<lines.length; i++) {
        elements.push(lines[i]);
        if (i < lines.length-1) {
            elements.push(<br key={i}/>);
        }
    }
    return elements;
}
```

This avoids the use of dangerously setting inner HTML.

(FWIW I figured this out by using the [Babel REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/).)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `<span>` for wrapping the the text and map for generation wrapped jsx,

```
{ address.split(',').map((addr, idx) => (<span key={idx}>{addr}<br/><span>) }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
{ address.split( ',' ).map( ( item ) => <> { item } <br /> </>) }
```

`<>...</>` is used for JSX to understand that code inside is HTML code.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst this doesn't directly result in it being separated by `<br />` I found a simpler solution that worked for us. Of course this depends on any padding or other CSS applied to `<div>` containers.

```
  {address.split(",").map((line) => (
    <div>{line}</div>
  ))}
```

You could also do:

```
  {address.split(",").map((line) => (
    <span style={{display: "block"}}>{line}</span>
  ))}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `React.Fragment` in place of `span`

```js
import { Fragment } from 'react'

const LineBreaks = ({ text = "", separator = ","}) => (
  <p>
    {text
      .split(separator)
      .map((text, index) => (
        <Fragment key={text}>
          {!!index && <br />}
          {text}
        </Fragment>
      ))}
  </p>
)
```